# i want to check the person in one table if valid enter his attdence

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i want to create an entry panel with text box using ajax and php it should verify the given id in one table if id is valid insert the id,date,time,status in another table

```
select id="$id" from table1 if id valid insert into table 2 '&id','&date','&time_stamp','&status'
```

the sample query i think.
for this i need the code please help me

```
id     | date        | time  |status
:----- | -----:      | :----:|-----|
2345   | 21/01/2017  | 12:13 am|in  |
```

> please validate the above example and help me in writing the correct query

Comment: You need to validate the input either in PHP or in JS (preferably both)

Comment: php combine with  ajax  for automatic accepting id number with out any event

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

in PHP (verify the id in a query like this):

```
select id from table1 where id = $id
```

if the query returns anything, proceed to the next query:

```
insert into table2 (value1, value2, value3) values ($v1, $v2, $v3)
```

jQuery side:

```
$.get("query.php", {id:id}).done(function(res){
  if (res.status=="success") alert("success");
  else alert("failed");
}
```

Comment: ` 
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT emp_id FROM tbl_employees WHERE emp_id=".$name =''); 
    if($name =''||$res =''){

Answer (score 0):

As @Nir suggested, you can check at sql:
If(Exists(select id from table1 where id = $id)) then
Begin
insert into table2 (value1, value2, value3) values ($v1, $v2, $v3)
End

And jquery part is also good. But you can add .fail function of ajax to handle any exception on php or SQL side.